# Collections.fill ArrayList with multiple values, not the same value

Tags: android, android-studio, arraylist

I'm using Android Studio where I have an array with a size of 126, and I initially fill them with 0's. Then I have an input with a size of 63, I want it to "replace" the first 126 values, instead of adding 63 to the 126.

For example I have an array of length 5 ( [0,0,0,0,0] ). Then I input 1,2,3 as individuals. I want it to look like [1,2,3,0,0] instead of [0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3]

example code:

```
ArrayList<Float> list = new ArrayList<Float>(Collections.<Float>nCopies(126, Float.valueOf(0)));
```

Then I add by (edited):

```
for (int j = 0; j < loop; j++) {
         float xx = result.multiHandLandmarks().get(i).getLandmark(j).getX();
         floaat yy = result.multiHandLandmarks().get(i).getLandmark(j).getY();
         float zz = result.multiHandLandmarks().get(i).getLandmark(j).getZ();
        list.add(xx);
        list.add(yy);
        list.add(zz);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
list.add(x.get(i))
```

it will be added to the end of the array.
use this :

```
list.add(i , x.get(i))
```

the first parameter is index, second is the value;

Comment: I tried, but no use. I updated my code to the actual loop I use.

Comment: @Hevarh as java documentation says: add(E e) -> Appends the specified element to the end of this list.  add(int index, E element)
Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add, that's the problem, you need to set.
For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < newList.size(); i++) { //like i < 63
                        oldList.set(i, newList.get(i)); //your new value
                    }
```